# (1) How to retain row heights even after sorting column. (2) Print two columns from a single column

Tags: google-sheets, ms-word, formatting

[**Google sheet Link**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pw_cFJipRhpA7bN3FyFTzE31CHSfU0RhqhXT3O1FTRg/edit?usp=sharing):

[image]

**I want to achieve 2 things:**

1. Sort Quality in A to Z order with same size of images, But when I Sort the image's size changes because sorting does not retain row heights as shown below:
   [image]
2. I want to print the sheet with 2 columns in a single page to utilize maximum space like this: [This_word_file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CMVut7p0MXovg3yRj-o2FrtPQUlaeMIr/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101462299931019949427&rtpof=true&sd=true)
   [image]
   which I have done it many times within seconds by simply copying the sheet column to MS Word & changing word layout to two columns BUT now suddenly (last successful copy and paste was in September 2021) when I paste the columns in word the images are getting cropped like: [this_word_file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1a2d0deJOO3pTyVufywzpLJqo0a02RFbH/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101462299931019949427&rtpof=true&sd=true)
   [image]

I am not looking for the final file, I want to learn the process to achieve these both.

Thank You

Comment: If you're looking at doing this with a formula then I think it's not possible. It should be possible if you do the sorting via an Apps Scirpt function, you can use [`setRowHeightsForced(startRow, numRows, height)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setrowheightsforcedstartrow,-numrows,-height) to specify exactly how tall the rows need to be.

Answer (score 0):

For adjusting the size of your cell to a certain size, as refereed in the comments, you can use `setRowHeightsForced(startRow, numRows, height)`.

First, if you are not familiar with Google Apps Script, you can follow up with this [guides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview).

After getting familiar with Google Apps Script, you can follow these steps:

1. In your script go to `Extension > Apps Script`
2. In your `Code.gs` file, copy this code:

Your question is too broad, please keep in mind this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to ask questions.

```js
const setFixedHeigth = () => {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]
  const range = sheet.getRange('D:D').getValues()
  for (let i = 0; i <= range.length; i++) {
    /* Check that the content is an image */
    if (range[i][0].valueType !== SpreadsheetApp.ValueType.IMAGE) return
    /* Change the rowHeigth to 200px */
    sheet.setRowHeightsForced(i + 1, 1, 200)
  }
}
```

This script will check all the `D` cells looking for an IMAGE, when found one, will change his size to `200px`.

##### Documentation

- [`setRowHeightsForced(startRow, numRows, height)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setrowheightsforcedstartrow,-numrows,-height)

Comment: My all images are of different sizes, so I want the script to change the row height to the height of the image contained in the cell. Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: are you there? It's really urgent!